# Generalized Wigner 3-j symbol and Legendre functions

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, real-analysis, qa.quantum-algebra, hypergeometric-functions

Let $P_{n}(x)$ the $n-th$ [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). It is well-knonw that $$\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x) P_m(x) P_h(x) \, dx=2\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
n & m & h\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)^{2}\tag{1}$$ where $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
n & m & h\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ is the [Wigner 3-j symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol). I know that there exist some possible choices for the generalization of the Wigner 3-j symbol to complex numbers but my question is: is it possible to extend othe Wigner 3-j symbol to complex numbers such that type (1) equation holds? In other words, is it possible to find a generalization of the 3-j symbols such that $$\int_{-1}^1 P_a(x)P_b(x)P_c(x) \, dx = f(a,b,c) \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)^{2}$$
for a suitable function $f$ depending on $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ and where $P_{a}(x)$ is the $C^{2}(-1,1)$ solution of the Legendre differential equation with parameter $a\in\mathbb{C}$, that is,

$$P_{a}(x)=\,_{2}F_{1}\left(a+1,-a;1;\frac{1-x}{2}\right)?$$

Comment: The 3j with all zero magnetic numbers has a closed form evaluation. This is Dixon's Theorem for 3F2 hypergeometric series, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262973/legendre-polynomials-triple-product so analytically continuing the RHS is trivial. Whenever you see $a!$ just replace that by $\Gamma(a+1)$, in terms of the Euler Gamma function. The question you should look at instead is what could be a definition of $P_a$ for $a$ complex? Perhaps, use the contour integral extraction formula from the generating function one over distance.

Comment: I am not aware of the existence of "some non equivalent definitions" for 3j symbols. Would care to explain?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I'm referring to the work of Raynal, On the definition and properties of generalized 3-j symbols, J. of Mathematical Physics, 19, 467–476 (1978). There doesn't seem to be anything newer about it, but I could be wrong. Maybe I have to specify that I intend "non-equivalent definitions" for the analytic continuation of the 3j symbols.

Comment: thanks for the ref to Raynal. Perhaps one can go around this because what you want here is not the analytic continuation of the general 3j with 6 free (or 5 with m conservation) parameters, but the continuation of the all m=0 case with 3 free parameters. There may be also a Carlson Theorem type argument which singles out a unique analytic continuation.

Comment: Thank you for the anonymous downvote without any comment, it surely help the community to improve itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Summary:** this is a topic of active research [1,2,3,4]; the answer to the general case is not known; answers exist for $a\in\mathbb{C}$, $b,c,\in\mathbb{N}$, and for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ with $b=c$.

---

**Case 1:** Consider first the case that one of the three parameters $a,b,c$ is complex, while the other two are still integers. For the Legendre function I use the representation
$$P_\mu(z)=\, _2F_1\left(-\mu,\mu+1;1;\frac{1-z}{2}\right),\;\;|1-z|<2,$$
and for the 3j symbol squared
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)^{2}=\frac{\binom{a+b-c}{\frac{1}{2} (a+b-c)} \binom{a-b+c}{\frac{1}{2} (a-b+c)} \binom{-a+b+c}{\frac{1}{2} (-a+b+c)}}{(a+b+c+1) \binom{a+b+c}{\frac{1}{2} (a+b+c)}}.$$
Then
$$\int_{-1}^1 P_{a}(x)P_{b}(x)P_c(x)\,dx=2\cos ^2\left(\tfrac{1}{2} \pi  (a+b+c)\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)^{2},$$
$$\text{for}\;\;a\in\mathbb{C},b\in\mathbb{N},c\in\mathbb{N}.$$
(I checked this with Mathematica, which can evaluate the integral in closed form.)

So in this case of one complex variable the function $f(a,b,c)$ in the OP equals $2\cos ^2\left(\tfrac{1}{2} \pi  (a+b+c)\right)$. Note that if all three variables are integers, the $\cos^2$ factor can be set to unity, since the 3j symbol equals zero for $a+b+c$ odd.

**Case 2:** If all three parameters are complex, a closed form expression in terms of generalized 3j symbols (or equivalently, generalized Clebsch-Gordan coefficients) exists for the integral
$$T_{\mu,\nu}=\int_{-1}^1 P_{\mu}(x)P_{\nu}(x)P_\nu(-x)\,dx,\;\;\mu,\nu\in\mathbb{C}.$$
Note the sign change of one argument of the Legendre function. For integer $\nu=n$ one would simply have $P_n(-x)=(-1)^nP_n(x)$, but for noninteger $\nu$ the sign change is essential.

The result, derived by Yajun Zhou [1] (see also [2,3,4]) is given below, it is lengthy. A simple case is $\mu=\nu$, when we have
$$\int_{-1}^1 P_{\nu}(x)P_{\nu}(x)P_\nu(-x)\,dx=\frac{1}{3} \bigl(2+3 \cos \pi  \nu+\cos 2 \pi  \nu\bigr)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\nu & \nu & \nu\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)^{2},\;\;\nu\in\mathbb{C}.$$
For integer $\nu$ the integral vanishes for $\nu$ odd, and for $\nu$ even the usual formula is recovered.

<sub>Here is the general result:
\begin{align}
T_{\mu,\nu}={}&\frac{2}{\pi^2}\frac{\sin(\mu\pi)\sin(\nu\pi)}{\mu(\mu+1)}\left[ \, \frac{1}{\nu}\,{_4F_3}\left(\left.\begin{array}{c}
1,\frac{1-\mu}{2},\frac{\mu+2 }{2},-\nu \\[4pt]
\frac{2-\mu }{2},\frac{\mu+3 }{2},1-\nu \\
\end{array}\right| 1\right) -\frac{1}{\nu+1} \,{ _4F_3}\left(\left.\begin{array}{c}
1,\frac{1-\mu}{2},\frac{\mu+2 }{2},\nu+1\ \\[4pt]
\frac{2-\mu }{2},\frac{\mu+3 }{2},\nu+2 \\
\end{array}\right| 1\right) \right].
\end{align}
The combination of two hypergeometric functions ensures the symmetry $T_{\mu,\nu}=T_{-\mu-1,\nu}=T_{\mu,-\nu-1}$, required by $P_{\mu}(z)=P_{-\mu-1}(z)$.</sub>

---

1. Yajun Zhou, [Legendre
   Functions, Spherical Rotations, and Multiple Elliptic Integrals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1735)
2. Marco Cantarini, [A
   note on    Clebsch-Gordan integral, Fourier-Legendre expansions and
   closed form    for hypergeometric series](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.11969)
3. John Campbell, [New Clebsch-Gordan-type integrals involving threefold products of complete elliptic  integrals](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.05819)
4. Yajun Zhou, [On Some Integrals Over the Product of Three Legendre Functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1606)

Comment: Sorry, just a question: what is your definition of 3-j symbols when the arguments are complex numbers?

Comment: see the second equation of my post; the binomial coefficients are written in terms of Gamma functions, which are then evaluated at complex arguments.